# Tem como eu salvar de um site publicado um arquivo no PC do usuário?

Tags: c#, mvc

Eu estou criando um arquivo zipado e preciso salvar ele para o meu usuário, só que quando eu seto o local aonde que q seja salvo o arquivo ele salva no servidor aonde o site está hospedado.

Caminho

```
string zip = @"C:\file.zip";
```

Passando para ser salvo...

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(zip, FileMode.Create))
```

Tem como eu salvar direto no PC do meu usuário?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode realizar a operação de download e deixar ele escolher o local para salvar.

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\folder\myfile.ext");
    string fileName = "myfile.ext";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

Comment: Legal, vou usar essa alternativa...